# Load existing class objects in JVM from another JVM

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, webserver

How to load existing class objects in JVM from another JVM?

I am analyzing a rare scenario in my server. I do not have proper logs in my sever to help me solve the situation and I believe that it can be a problem with a particular class object (user defined).

Say for example below is the class:

```
public class MyRequest 
{
  public byte[] getData()
  {
    return somdata;
  }
}
```

Currently in my server's JVM, 100's of the above class object is in my JVM's memory. I want to know if there is a possibility to load all the 100 objects and access their data/method (`getData()`).
I do not want to create an new instance of the MyRequest class (that I know is pretty easy). I want to load the existing objects from my JVM through another Java process.

P.S : I can not kill my server for any reason.
P.S : And I can not install any tools like visualvm etc and more over tools tell us the objects type,memory but not the exact data.

Comment: If you run into this situation where the JVM is still running you can at least attach with visualvm and do a memory profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it won't work.

1. If you can't attach a debugger, you can't do anything.
2. If you *could* attach a debugger, you should be able find and look at those instances, but you won't be able to get them to do something they weren't designed to do.  In particular, if they are not designed to be serializable, you won't be able to serialize them.

I think your best bet is to change your server code to improve the logging, and then restart it with a debugger agent ... and wait for the problem to recur.

And of course, if you have a debugger attached, you don't need to move objects to another JVM.  You can just look at their state directly.

---

However, there's a catch.  Many "amazingly rare" scenarios are actually related to threading, thread-safety and timing problems.  And many things you can do to observe the effects of a such a bug are liable to alter the program's behaviour.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> So if we know the starting address of the Virtual memory for that JVM...can we not know the data? assuming all objects are within the JVM memory space.

It is not as simple as that:

- Locations of objects on the Java heap are not predictable.
- Locations of thread stacks are not predictable.
- and so on.

It *may be* theoretically possible to dump the memory of any process, and reconstruct the execution state of the JVM, and "read" the state of the objects.  But you'd need specialized tools and/or a great deal of knowledge of JVM internals to do this.  I'm not even sure if the tools exist ...

In short, it is not practical, AFAIK.

Comment: Well said and I thought so.but I had little hope of 1 thing..basically when you load a JVM in RAM all the class objects are gonna be in that particular RAM virtual memory space.. So if we know the starting address of the Virtual memory for that JVM...can we not know the data? assuming all objects are within the JVM memory space.

Answer (score 1):

Objects and their references (aliases) are bound to the current running JVM. There is no possibility to share them between several JVMs.

If you want to "share" data between two JVMs, you must serialize this data, which means sending them from on JVM to the other. This also requires the classes, whose instances shall be serialized, to implement the interface [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Note, that [arrays automatically implement Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1).

You can either stream those serializable objects yourself using sockets, output and input streams (which is much effort) or you can use [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) for calling remote methods and just stream your data. In either case, all objects are copied and built up again in the other JVM. There is no chance to have them shared.

In case of application servers, RMI calls are typically invoked by just using EJBs. But you need an application server; just using a web server is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
Load existing class objects in JVM from another JVM
```

Its not possible

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can tell the JVM to dump its state - with a kill signal or similar - to disk so you can use post-Mortem tools to analyze the state of your program.

Keywords are "core" and "hprof" and I have not done this myself yet.